# System error:unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, line, eof, glove

`with open("glove.6B.50d.txt",encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        values = line.split()
        word = values[0]
        vector = np.asarray(values[1:], "float32")
        embeddings_dict[word] = vector`

This is the code i executed,

I am getting error while running this part of the code. tried some of the existing solutions, none of them helped

[this is the error i am getting while i was executing the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfPSz.png)

Comment: Please copypaste your code instead of capturing them and uploading them as an image.

Comment: Don't post your code instead of images.

Comment: Where are you executing this code? spyder or ipython notebook?

Comment: i executed the code in spyder